# Tilled under buckwheat, how long to wait before replanting?

Tags: cover-crop

I planted a small plot to buckwheat as a green manure / cover crop this spring. Today I chopped it down, put the cuttings in the compost, and tilled the stubble under.

I'd like to make another planting of buckwheat (it's only 40d to flower), but I'm wondering if I should wait before I replant or would it be ok to spread some seed tomorrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just spoke with the owner of our local feed mill (he also farms a few acres locally), he said they is no reason (he knows of) why you can't sow more buckwheat immediately after what you've done.

Comment: Thanks. I happened to be doing a bit of reading tonight that confirms your answer and my hesitation: if I had tilled in the stalks, the decomposing mass would be eating so much nitrogen and offgassing so much CO2 that it would make it hard for seeds to germinate. By moving it to the compost pile and just tilling in stubble it should be ok -- I seeded today.

Comment: @bstpierre, no worries & good information to know. Good luck :)